# I need to Sum the count of (Account No_) column and get the result that is above to 2

Tags: sql

I need to Sum the count of (Account No_) column and get the result that is above to 2

```
 Document No_        Date       Account No_
00000P2312000129529 03/10/2019  CON015447
00000P2322000094989 03/10/2019  CON015447
00000P2322000094996 03/10/2019  CON027288
00000P2314000038573 03/10/2019  CON027288
00000P2314000038572 03/10/2019  CON027288
00000P2327000065555 03/10/2019  TCO260379
00000P2337000155790 03/10/2019  TCO260379
00000P2311000160826 03/10/2019  TCO260379
00000P2331000013610 03/10/2019  TCO260379
```

I need the result to be the count of (Account No_) column and get the result that is above to 2

```
Document No_          Date      Account No_    Account No_  Count
00000P2322000094996 03/10/2019  CON027288          3
00000P2314000038573 03/10/2019  CON027288          3
00000P2314000038572 03/10/2019  CON027288          3
00000P2327000065555 03/10/2019  TCO260379          4
00000P2337000155790 03/10/2019  TCO260379          4
00000P2311000160826 03/10/2019  TCO260379          4
00000P2331000013610 03/10/2019  TCO260379          4
```

Comment: Please tell your problem more briefly

Comment: What is your DBMS product?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use group by and having in a subquery :

```
SELECT t1.document_no_, t1.date, t1.account_no_, t3.account_no_count FROM document t1
JOIN (
     SELECT account_no_, COUNT(1) AS account_no_count
     FROM document t2
     GROUP BY account_no_
     HAVING COUNT(1) >= 3
  ) t3 ON t1.account_no_ = t3.account_no_
```

[**FIND A DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/689374/8)

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, 
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [Account No_])AS [Account No_Count] 
    FROM TheTable
) T WHERE [Account No_Count]  >=3
```

Comment: This is the right solution.  I removed the reference to SQL Server 2012 because the OP does not specify that s/he is using SQL Server.  And window functions are standard and supported by all major databases (and most minor ones).